# What is the proper way to unload/unbind a record from a form in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to allow users to create new records and edit existing records from the same form in ExtJS 4. I am working with ExtJS 4.0.7.

It's easy for me to load a record.

```
var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myForm');
form.loadRecord(record);
```

But if I want to start fresh, there is no way to unload it! At least, no proper way that I can find. I've already researched for hours, and even looked through some of the core Ext code for an answer. The best I could come up with to "unload" a record is:

```
form._record = null;
```

If I don't explicitly declare `_record` as `null`, Ext will always try to update the record stored there. `form.reset();` does not clear the loaded record either.

Is there a "proper" way to clear the record tied to a form so that a new record can be saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ext.form.Panel` is derived from `Ext.form.Basic`, where _record exists as a private variable. And if you take a look into the code of `Ext.form.Basic`
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-method-getRecord
you'll note that there is no clear method for _record. `reset` method just do reset of form fields.
So you're doing right when setting `form._record = null;`
Personally, I'd prefer to do `delete form._record`, but your approach should work either.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs describe](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) that the `reset` method's optional first parameter to true unbinds any record set by loadRecord. So in Ext 4 and 5 you can just do:

```
yourForm.reset(true);
```

Internally it does:

```
delete me._record;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try making a blank record and loading that to clear the form and record.

```
var blankRecord = Ext.create('YourModel');
yourForm.loadRecord(blankRecord);
```